# Cannot find filesystem

Tags: pi-zero, cross-compilation, toolchain

Still scraping rust off of C++ and learning CLion, Raspberry Pi and Cmake. I am following https://blog.monotok.org/compile-locally-run-raspberry-pi-via-clion/ to cross-compile on my Ubuntu platform.

I have code that compiles fine locally, but when I cross-compile for raspberry pi, I get the following:

```
====================[ Build | rookery_exe | Raspberry Pi Release ]==============
/snap/bin/cmake --build /tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/cmake-build-raspberry-pi-release --target rookery_exe -- -j 12
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/CodeSource.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/ArduinoSourceProperties.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/Arduino.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/WorkFile.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/PropertiesFile.cpp.o
/tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/src/core/WorkFile.cpp:1:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/src/core/CodeSource.cpp:2:0:
/tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/src/core/Arduino.h:5:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
gmake[3]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/build.make:111: src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/CodeSource.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[3]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/build.make:150: src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/WorkFile.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/src/core/ArduinoSourceProperties.cpp:1:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
gmake[3]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/build.make:85: src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/ArduinoSourceProperties.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/src/core/PropertiesFile.cpp:3:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
gmake[3]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/build.make:124: src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/PropertiesFile.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/src/core/Arduino.cpp:7:0:
/tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/src/core/Arduino.h:5:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
gmake[3]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/build.make:72: src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/Arduino.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:203: src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:236: src/exe/CMakeFiles/rookery_exe.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:182: rookery_exe] Error 2
```

Maybe the cross compiler uses an older version of C++ that doesn't have file system? Is there a way to fix that? Maybe a compile flag?

Comment: Does any of these two links work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867379/why-does-gcc-not-seem-to-have-the-filesystem-standard-library https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=270001

Comment: I should have indicated that I found those articles. If it's the linker flag, where do I set it up in CLion?

Comment: I have to google. I don't use CLion

Comment: Use the cmake directive `target_link_libraries()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [raspberrypi/tools](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) toolchain you seem to be using contains an ancient version of GCC (4.9.3). If you want to use the `<filesystem>` header, you need GCC 8 or later.

You can use [Crosstool-NG](https://crosstool-ng.github.io/) to configure and build a newer toolchain.
Alternatively, you can find the toolchains I'm using here: [tttapa/tttapa/RPi-Cpp-Toolchain](https://github.com/tttapa/RPi-Cpp-Toolchain). The pre-built Docker container you can download ships with GCC 9.2.0, but you can change that in the ct-ng config files, e.g. [here](https://github.com/tttapa/RPi-Cpp-Toolchain/blob/578428f2dc62c769023d7051c2ee5528e9e6c082/toolchain/docker/merged/cross-toolchain/aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu.config#L486), or by following [these instructions](https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Raspberry-Pi/C++-Development/Building-The-Toolchain.html#customizing-the-toolchain).
I'm sure there are other distributions of newer toolchains for the Raspberry Pi as well, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Ack! How did you find the version of gcc I'm using? I don't see it in the text.

Comment: @Thom from your mention of the raspberrypi/tools in your other post, you can see the version here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf, or you can verify it yourself using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version`

Comment: I have my project building with this. Cheers for this. Where does the executable go?

Comment: @Thom which executable? The one you built is probably in a “build” folder somewhere.

Comment: looked under the tmp directory, and the project directory and couldn't find a dir named build. This is annoying. It says Build files have been written to: /tmp/tmp.UNnm1OGKQ2/cmake-build-raspberry-pi-release